# Использование css-анимации для перемещения элемента div в каждый угол страницы

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, svg, css-animation

Я новичок в сцене анимации css. Я хотел бы узнать, как использовать анимацию css, чтобы элемент div круга переходил в каждый угол страницы.
Я пытался сделать это, но безрезультатно, пожалуйста, помогите.
Довольно простой вопрос, но он поможет мне понять, как работает css анимация.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>CSS 201</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Pacifico&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
  .box {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 10px solid black;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    animation: myAnimation 4s infinite alternate,myAnimation2 4s infinite alternate;
  }
  @keyframes myAnimation {
    0% { top: 0; left: 0; }
    30% { top: 3000px; }
    68%, 72% { left: 50px; }
    100% { top: 3000px; left: 90%; }
  }

  @keyframes myAnimation2{
    0% { bottom: 0; right: 0; }
    30% { top: 3000px; }
    68%, 72% { left: 50px; }
    100% { top: 3000px; left: 90%; }
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="box"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Using css animation to make a div element move to each corner of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66812538/7394871) от участника  [@иStefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15484301/stefan).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/66812538/7394871

Comment: Добавлен новый [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66824584/7394871) - решение SVG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CSS Only**

```css
.box {
  position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 180px; height: 180px;
  border: 5px solid #9D8500; border-radius: 5px; background: green;
}

.blue, .red, .yellow {
  position: absolute; width: 13px; height: 13px; border-radius: 15px;
}

.blue {background: blue; animation: bX 1.5s linear 0s infinite alternate, bY 2s linear 0s infinite alternate;}
.red {background: red; animation: rX 2s linear 0s infinite alternate, rY 2.5s linear 0s infinite alternate;}
.yellow {background: yellow; animation: yX 3s linear 0s infinite, yY 3s linear 0s infinite;}

@keyframes bX {from {left: 0;} to {left: 167px;}}
@keyframes bY {from {top: 0;} to {top: 167px;}}
@keyframes rX {from {right: 0;} to {right: 167px;}}
@keyframes rY {from {bottom: 0;} to {bottom: 167px;}}
@keyframes yX {from {left: 167px;} to {left: 0;}}
@keyframes yY {0% {top: 0; left: 0;} 25% {top: 0; left: 167px;} 50% {top: 167px; left: 167px;} 75% {top: 167px; left: 0;} 100% {top: 0; left: 0;}}
```

```html
<div class="box"><div class="blue"></div><div class="red"></div><div class="yellow"></div></div>
```

Comment: Отличный ответ! Долго смотрел на код и результаты работы. Хорошо бы добавить масштабируемость и усложнить повторяемость, так как траектории шариков повторяются через 2 цикла. Но это всё мелочи. Хорошая работа!

Answer (score 6):

В своем решении я использовал `transform: translate() translateY()`, чтобы не допустить, чтобы анимированный объект создавал переполнение.

В этом решении второй `@keyframes` с именем `myAnimation2` был удален, так как в этом коде не было смысла.

Кроме того, я уменьшил размер анимированного элемента для лучшего визуального восприятия анимации в моем примере.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 10px solid black;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    animation: myAnimation 4s infinite;
}

@keyframes myAnimation {
    0% {
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        transform: translate(0) translateY(0);
    }
    25% {
        top: 100%;
        left: 0;
        transform: translateX(0) translateY(-100%);
    }
    50% {
        top: 100%;
        left: 100%;
        transform: translateX(-100%) translateY(-100%);
    }
    75% {
        top: 0;
        left: 100%;
        transform: translateX(-100%) translateY(0);
    }
    100% {
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        transform: translateX(0) translateY(0);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66813127/7394871) от участника  [@s.kuznetsov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13573444/s-kuznetsov).</sub>

Answer (score 5):

Более простая идея с использованием фона без сложных ключевых кадров:

```css
.box {
  background:
    radial-gradient(farthest-side,black 97%,transparent) 
    top left/100px 100px /* simply adjust the values here to control the size of the circle */
    no-repeat;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  animation: move 4s infinite;
}

@keyframes move {
  25% { background-position: bottom left  }
  50% { background-position: bottom right }
  75% { background-position: top    right }
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66814235/7394871) от участника  [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Изменения в правилах CSS  вопроса

```css
.box {
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        border: 10px solid black;
        background-color: black;
        border-radius: 50%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;

        animation: myAnimation 4s infinite;

    }
    @keyframes myAnimation {
        5% { top: 0; left: 0; }
        25% { top: 200px; left: 0px; }
        50% { top: 200px; left: calc(100% - 320px); }
        75% { top: 0px; left: calc(100% - 320px); }
        100% { top: 0px; left: 0; }
    }
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66812601/7394871) от участника  [@Lalji Tadhani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4095056/lalji-tadhani).</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Рассмотрите возможность использования SMIL SVG для решения этого вопроса.
На мой взгляд SMIL  это мощная и гибкая платформа для реализации анимаций, которая легка в настройке и не требует, как анимация CSS пересчета таймингов, в случае изменения логики приложения.

Гибкость smil заключается в том, что достаточно изменить логические цепочки, определяющие последовательность анимаций, и это даст возможность полностью пересобрать приложение, не затрачивая значительных усилий на пересчет таймингов.

***1#. Решение примера из вопроса: один шар перемещается в углы страницы.***

Для этого достаточно задать координаты углов в атрибуте `values` и шар будет перемещаться по углам страницы

Анимация начнется после клика

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="100vw"     height="95vh" viewBox="0 0 400 400" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >  
<defs>
<radialGradient id="gradB" cx="20%" cy="20%" r="100%" fx="30%" fy="30%">
   <stop stop-color="white" offset="0"/>
   <stop stop-color="blue" offset="25%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,192)" offset="50%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,127)" offset="70%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,64)" offset="85%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,0)" offset="100%"/>
 </radialGradient>
</defs>  
<rect x="10" y="10" width="380" height="380" rx="25"  fill="green" stroke="#9D8500" stroke-width="15"/>  
<circle cx="30" cy="30" r="3%" fill="url(#gradB)" >
  <animateTransform
    attributeName="transform"
    type="translate"
    begin="svg1.click"
    dur="9s"
    restart="whenNotActive"
    repeatCount="indefinite"
    fill="freeze"
    values="
       0,0;
       340,0;
       340,340;
       0,340;
       0,0;
       0,0" />
</circle>
</svg>
```

***#2. Добавлены паузы при приходе шарика в углы***

Для реализации пауз анимации в углах дублируются координаты этих углов

```
 values="
       0,0;
       340,0;
       340,0;
       340,340;
       340,340;
       0,340;
       0,340;
       0,0;
       0,0" />
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="100vw"     height="95vh" viewBox="0 0 400 400" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >  
<defs>
<radialGradient id="gradB" cx="20%" cy="20%" r="100%" fx="30%" fy="30%">
   <stop stop-color="white" offset="0"/>
   <stop stop-color="blue" offset="25%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,192)" offset="50%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,127)" offset="70%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,64)" offset="85%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,0)" offset="100%"/>
 </radialGradient>
</defs>  
<rect x="10" y="10" width="380" height="380" rx="25"  fill="green" stroke="#9D8500" stroke-width="15"/>  
<circle cx="30" cy="30" r="3%" fill="url(#gradB)" >
  <animateTransform
    attributeName="transform"
    type="translate"
    begin="svg1.click"
    dur="9s"
    restart="whenNotActive"
    repeatCount="indefinite"
    fill="freeze"
    values="
       0,0;
       340,0;
       340,0;
       340,340;
       340,340;
       0,340;
       0,340;
       0,0;
       0,0" />
</circle>
```

***#3. Анимация двух шаров***

Запуском второй анимации (красного шара) управляет логическая цепочка

`begin="anBlue.begin+3s"`

Словами можно сказать, что анимация красного шарика начнется через `3s` после старта анимации голубого шарика.
*Вот это и есть логические цепочки, который управляют последовательностью выполнения анимаций.*

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="100vw"     height="95vh" viewBox="0 0 400 400" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >  
<defs>
<radialGradient id="gradB" cx="20%" cy="20%" r="100%" fx="30%" fy="30%">
   <stop stop-color="white" offset="0"/>
   <stop stop-color="blue" offset="25%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,192)" offset="50%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,127)" offset="70%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,64)" offset="85%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,0)" offset="100%"/>
 </radialGradient> 
 <radialGradient id="gradR" cx="20%" cy="20%" r="100%" fx="30%" fy="30%">
   <stop stop-color="white" offset="0"/>
   <stop stop-color="red" offset="25%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(192,0,0)" offset="50%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(127,0,0)" offset="70%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(64,0,0)" offset="85%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,0)" offset="100%"/>
 </radialGradient>
</defs>  
<rect x="10" y="10" width="380" height="380" rx="25"  fill="green" stroke="#9D8500" stroke-width="15"/>  
   <!-- Red ball -->

<circle cx="30" cy="30" r="3%" fill="url(#gradR)" >
   <!-- Red ball animation  -->
 <animateTransform id="anRed"
    attributeName="transform"
    type="translate"
    begin="anBlue.begin+3s"
    dur="9s"
    restart="whenNotActive"
    repeatCount="indefinite"
    fill="freeze"
    values="
       0,0;
       340,0;
       340,0;
       340,340;
       340,340;
       0,340;
       0,340;
       0,0;
       0,0" />
</circle> 
  <!-- Blue ball -->
<circle cx="30" cy="30" r="3%" fill="url(#gradB)" >
     <!-- Blue ball animation -->
  <animateTransform id="anBlue"
    attributeName="transform"
    type="translate"
    begin="svg1.click"
    dur="9s"
    restart="whenNotActive"
    repeatCount="indefinite"
    fill="freeze"
    values="
       0,0;
       340,0;
       340,0;
       340,340;
       340,340;
       0,340;
       0,340;
       0,0;
       0,0" />
</circle> 
</svg>
```

[BONUS]

***#4. Вариант с хаотичным отскоком шаров от бортов коробки***

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="100vh" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
<defs>
 <radialGradient id="gradB" cx="20%" cy="20%" r="100%" fx="30%" fy="30%">
   <stop stop-color="white" offset="0"/>
   <stop stop-color="blue" offset="25%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,192)" offset="50%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,127)" offset="70%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,64)" offset="85%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,0)" offset="100%"/>
 </radialGradient>

 <radialGradient id="gradR" cx="20%" cy="20%" r="100%" fx="30%" fy="30%">
   <stop stop-color="white" offset="0"/>
   <stop stop-color="red" offset="25%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(192,0,0)" offset="50%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(127,0,0)" offset="70%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(64,0,0)" offset="85%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,0)" offset="100%"/>
 </radialGradient>
 </defs>
<rect width="100%" height="100%" rx="25"  fill="green" stroke="#9D8500" stroke-width="15"/>
<circle cx="50%" cy="20%" r="3%" fill="url(#gradB)" >
 <animate attributeName="cx" dur="3" values="3%;97%;3%"  
   repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
 <animate attributeName="cy" dur="2.8" values="3%;97%;3%"  
   repeatCount="indefinite" />
</circle>
<circle cx="30%" cy="70%" r="3%" fill="url(#gradR)" >
 <animate attributeName="cx" dur="2.7" values="97%;3%;97%"  
   repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
 <animate attributeName="cy" dur="3.1" values="3%;97%;3%"  
   repeatCount="indefinite" />
</circle>
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66824584/7394871) от участника  [@Alexandr_TT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7394871/alexandr-tt).</sub>